# Locate all "light bulb" actions in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way to display all of the places where Roslyn has determined that there is a style change to be made (i.e. a light bulb shows up)? I'd like to see them all in a list similar to the errors/warnings tab.

This appears to be different than both build and Intellisense warnings/errors. For instance, if I have an unused "using" statement in my C# file, this qualifies for a quick action (i.e. light bulb), but doesn't show up in the list of warnings and errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where has the Code Analysis window gone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615394/where-has-the-code-analysis-window-gone)

Answer (score 3):

Just to summarize the answer, you can see all the "light bulbs" (quick action, fix or screwdriver) in the **Error List** window (in View menu); you need the **Messages button** to be enabled (next to errors and warnings) and **only the items for the documents currently opened** are displayed.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to find them in the Build window (use Build + IntelliSense). You may also want to take a look at [JetBrains ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com), it has a dedicated window for code issues and picks up a good bit more than the native VS analysis does.

Comment: Where is the "Build" window?  Did you mean "Error List" window?  No light bulb actions are shown when "Build + IntelliSense" is selected in the Error List.